# ARC on OS X: different behavior in debug vs release config

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

Consider the app below. When I run this app in debug configuration, `textStorage` is always *non-nil* at the `NSLog()` line.

However, when I run the app in release configuration, `textStorage` is always *nil* at the `NSLog()` line. This makes sense, since `textStorage` goes unused after being allocated so ARC deallocs it immediately (`layoutManager` must hold a weak back reference that nils out).

**But why would the app exhibit different behavior in debug configuration? What is ARC doing differently and why?**

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = nil;
    NSTextContainer *textContainer = nil;
    NSTextStorage *textStorage = nil;
    if (YES) {
        textStorage = [[NSTextStorage alloc] initWithString:@"test"];
        textContainer = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithContainerSize:NSMakeSize(100, 100)];
        layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init];
        [layoutManager addTextContainer:textContainer];
        [textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
    }
    NSLog(@"breakpoint here!");
}

@end
```

Comment: My guess would be *optimization*.

Comment: Only you can answer this definitively. Profile the app in debug and look at the reference count history. As a guess, something in `-addLayoutManager:` does `[self retain]; [self autorelease];` when in debug.

Comment: @trojanfoe is correct. It is the optimizaton. Try it for yourself: Go to 'Build Settings' and set the 'Optimization level' for the debug build to anything else than none.

Comment: Both behaviours are valid. Compilers produce different valid behaviour when optimising code.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/26583061/1803879 and through debugging a similar issue, ARC behaves differently for `debug` vs `release`.