# Assigning retained object to weak property

Tags: ios, objective-c, retain

I am using **Xcode 6** and I have created my app with a `UITableView` and a `custom Cell` in it.
This is my `custom cell`

```
@interface SuggestingTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesOne;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesTwo;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesThree;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesFour;

@end
```

As you can see I have four `IBOutets` to a `SuggestedSeriesView` that is a subclass of `UIView`.
In the `TableView DataSource` methods I have created these `SuggestedSeriesView` and assign them like:

```
cellIdentifier = suggestionCell;
SuggestingTableViewCell *suggesting = (SuggestingTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:suggestionCell];
Series *ser1 = series[0];
suggesting.seriesOne = [[SuggestedSeriesView alloc] initWithFrame:suggesting.seriesOne.bounds
                                                    andSeriesData:@{JV_SERIES_IMAGE_URL : ser1.imageURL,
                                                                    JV_SERIES_TITLE : ser1.title}];
Series *ser2 = series[1];
suggesting.seriesTwo = [[SuggestedSeriesView alloc] initWithFrame:suggesting.seriesTwo.bounds
                                                    andSeriesData:@{JV_SERIES_IMAGE_URL : ser2.imageURL,
                                                                    JV_SERIES_TITLE : ser2.title}];
Series *ser3 = series[2];
suggesting.seriesThree = [[SuggestedSeriesView alloc] initWithFrame:suggesting.seriesThree.bounds
                                                      andSeriesData:@{JV_SERIES_IMAGE_URL : ser3.imageURL,
                                                                      JV_SERIES_TITLE : ser3.title}];
Series *ser4 = series[3];

suggesting.seriesFour = [[SuggestedSeriesView alloc] initWithFrame:suggesting.seriesFour.bounds
                                                     andSeriesData:@{JV_SERIES_IMAGE_URL : ser4.imageURL,
                                                                     JV_SERIES_TITLE : ser4.title}];
```

The compiler gives me the warning that :

> Assigning retained object to weak property; object will be released after assignment

Why this is happening to the `SuggestedSeriesView` gets retained by the `cell` because it has no `IBOutlet`?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No, it isn't and it's exactly the point. Retaining does not occur because stuff is `IBOutlet` but because stuff is `strong`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This happens because your properties are weak, this means they will not retain anything, they can only reference stuff.

IBOutlet is equal to void, it is just a hint for xcode to tell it "this can be connected on the interface builder".

The reason why properties from the interface builder are of type weak and IBOutlet is because, they are retained by the storyboard's View controller's view itself, so if you make a view controller in the interface builder, and add a view, and THEN link this view in code your property doesn't have to be strong, since its already retained by the one of the views.

You should change those properties to

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) SuggestedSeriesView *seriesOne;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SuggestedSeriesView *seriesTwo;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SuggestedSeriesView *seriesThree;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SuggestedSeriesView *seriesFour;
```

Comment: _"they are retained by the storyboard's View controller"_ this is not correct. Outlets can be weak because they are subviews of something, and a superview maintains a strong reference to its subviews.

Answer (score 10):

You are creating an object at the same time as assigning it to a weak property. At this point, nothing has a strong reference to it, so under the rules of ARC it should be immediately nilled out. (Note than when running debug builds, this does not happen straight away).

When loading from the storyboard the object is created, added as a subview and *then* assigned to the outlet. The superview has a strong reference so this is fine.

To mirror this behaviour without changing your outlet property type (though to be honest, there's not much harm in that nowadays) you should assign your new object to a local variable, then add it to a view, then assign it to the outlet property.

Comment: OK Thank you, i think i'll change the property attribute for now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface SuggestingTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet SuggestedSeriesView *seriesOne;

@end

cellIdentifier = suggestionCell;

SuggestingTableViewCell *suggesting = (SuggestingTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:suggestionCell];

Series *ser1 = series[0];

SuggestedSeriesView * strongSeriesOne = [[SuggestedSeriesView alloc] initWithFrame:suggesting.seriesOne.bounds andSeriesData:@{JV_SERIES_IMAGE_URL : ser1.imageURL, JV_SERIES_TITLE : ser1.title}];

suggesting.seriesOne = strongSeriesOne;
```